# Know the parent of a space

Tags: wiki, velocity, xwiki

I'm building a custom panel for my Xwiki (Cloud hosted). I need to do a hierarchy tree on my panel, and for that, I need to know the parent of a space, so I can do an #if clause...

```
#set ($spaces = $xwiki.spaces)
#set ($hiddenSpaces = ["XWiki", "Admin", "Panels", "Blog", "Main"])
#foreach ($space in $spaces)
```

Here.. how can I achieve something like '$space.parent', that works on a doc????

Like I said I have tried with $space.parent, but this is not working.. it just prints it out on my screen...

Please, I'm stuck on this

EDIT: I think the objects returned by $xwiki.spaces are Strings... is there a way to get a space from the xwiki, something like $xwiki.getSpace($space).parent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such thing as a *the parent of a space* yet, since XWiki only has documents represented in the database. However, by convention the space is usually represented by its *homepage*, `SpaceName.WebHome`. So, you should check the parent on this document.

```
#set ($spaces = $xwiki.spaces)
#set ($hiddenSpaces = ["XWiki", "Admin", "Panels", "Blog", "Main"])
#foreach ($space in $spaces)
  #set ($spaceHome = $xwiki.getDocument("${space}.WebHome"))
  #set ($spaceParent = $spaceHome.parent)
  ... and the rest of the code ...
#end
```

But this uses slightly deprecated methods. You should use entity references instead of strings:

```
  #set ($spaceHome = $xwiki.getDocument($services.model.createDocumentReference($doc.documentReference.wikiReference.name, $space, '', 'default')))
```

Comment: Thank you that helped me.. I'm almost there, now in my foreach, everything is getting obtained....how can i filter out the pages? I only need the spaces.. i think im missing a condition here?

#set($query3="where doc.parent='$rdoc2'")

Comment: Again, there are only documents, while the spaces are virtual. You can't filter out documents from a query, since any (public) query returns just documents. You can do `where doc.parent='$rdoc2' and doc.name = 'WebHome'` to select only space homepages, or you can use the PR-protected `$xwiki.search("select doc.space from XWikiDocument doc where doc.parent = '$rdoc2'")`, but Programming Rights queries should only be used in extreme cases.